# How to profile VSCode? It eats too much CPU in idle

Tags: plugins, profiling

Since recently, VSCode started to eat 90% CPU per window even in idle mode. I suspect, some of plugins could be responsible for it.

Is there a way to somehow profile VSCode, so I could find the offending plugin?

I had a clean installation on another machine with minimal amount of plugins, and the problem is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have settings-sync extension.  Its known for high CPU utilization. Disable it, restart VSCode, kill Code helper (all) and start again. it will use again 100% for few seconds and it will drop to normal 8-10%

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! I ended up with disabling the extensions until I saw it stopping eating the CPU. I really wonder, why the author is not fixing it... but that's for another day,